# Couchbase Full Text Search fuzziness matches more than I expect

Tags: database, full-text-search, couchbase

Below is the structure of my document in Couchbase:

```
{
  "firstName": "Anna Maria",
  "lastName": "Smith",
}
```

I execute this query where I want to get all the documents with firstName equals "Anna Maria" along with fuzziness level 1.

```
select individual.firstName, individual.lastName
from mybucket as individual
where SEARCH(individual.firstName, "Anna Maria~1")
```

Below is the Full Text Search index I have created with the analyzer set to **keyword**, which it is supposed to create a single token representing the entire input, force exact matches and preserve characters such as spaces.

[image]

However, the "Anna Maria" is splitted into two words and the result of the query is documents with firstName equals to "Anna" or "Maria" or "Anna Maria". I want only results with firstName equals to "Anna Maria", along with the fuzziness ("Anna Marias", "Anna Mario", etc).